# Google Calendar API - How to set Auto Join option for event participant

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have create an Event using Google Calendar API using 'hangoutsMeet' option.

However, despite being event participant, end users are getting 'Ask to join' button.

Is there any option which could allow event participant to join automatically without approval.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing) on the day of this post it is **not possible** to automatically join participants to **individual events** as they will be required to **accept or reject the event invitation**.

From the documentation linked above:

> Inviting someone to an event will put a copy of that event on their calendar. The invitee can then accept or reject the invitation, and to some extent also modify their copy of the event.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)